# How can i handle to Exception in Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, exception, mockito

i want to test exception handling in my method..
i tried to doThrow() and willThrow()

```
given(landlineCodeDAO.findByCode(anyString())).willThrow(new Throwable("Exception occurred by TestCase"));

String resultResponse = ws.delete(memberUid, partitionUid, landlineCodeIn);

assertThat(resultResponse, is("{\"result\":\"failed\",\"result_code\":\"exception\"}"));
```

it is my test code

and.....it is my method

```
catch (Throwable e) {

            JFLogger.logger(getClass()).error("add() ", e);

            try {

                response.put("result", "failed");
                response.put("result_code", "exception");
                JFLogger.logger(getClass()).debug("{}", response.toString());

            } catch (Throwable th) {
            }
        }
        return response.toString();
```

this case return finished.

but...

```
given(landlineCodeDAO.findByCode(anyString())).willThrow(new Throwable("Exception occurred by TestCase"));

String resultResponse = ws.delete(memberUid, partitionUid, landlineCodeIn);

assertThat(resultResponse, is("{\"result123123\":\"fail123123ed\",\"res123ult_code\":\"excepti123123on\"}"));
```

it also return finished..

how can i checked resultResponse ?

---

i'm young korean student and my english is not good.. 
so, please understand this question.

Comment: Are you saying that both tests (one expecting the correct result and one expecting an incorrect result with garbage characters inserted) executed with no error?  What do you see if you call System.out.println(resultResponse) in each test (just for debugging the tests)?

Comment: i can see just "Process finished with exit code 0"...
and i can't see System.out.println(resultResponse) 's result
because Code under the"given(landlineCodeDAO.findByCode(anyString())).willThrow(new Throwable("Exception occurred by TestCase"));" does not working...

Comment: Are you running the test in JUnit?

Comment: yes, i use the JUnit

Comment: It's difficult to understand your question, so I will try to re-phrase what I think I do understand:   You run 2 tests in JUnit (it sounds like you're launching it from IntelliJ).  One of them should succeed and does, and one contains an error in `assertThat` and should fail but does not fail.

Comment: You will either need to step through the tests in the debugger or try some other tests to see what is going on. If you write a test which contains only `Assert.fail("test");` or `Assert.assertFalse(true);`, what happens? If you change your `assertThat` to `assertEquals`, what happens?